# Can I let the code-behind file for a WCF service be a T4 file?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, t4, code-behind

In creating a WCF service (filetype .svc) in Visual Studio 2010, I'd like to make the C# code-behind file (.svc.cs) into a T4 file (.tt). How can I do this, if at all possible?

**EDIT:**
Note that I am writing the WCF service itself, not a client.

Comment: +1 for clarifying. New answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated answer based on clarification of question.*

### If you want to template the service.svc.cs file do this:

- Open the service.svc.cs file and save it as a .TT extension. This will cause the svc.cs file to automatically vanish (I assume because of the class defined in it).
- Ensure the Build Action is set to "content".
- Ensure the custom build option of the service.svc.tt file is TextTemplatingFileGenerator.
- Add the language type you want to use for your TT scripting to the top of the Reference.tt file (always good to be explicit):

  <#@ template language="C#" #>
- Click save while the .tt file is open, at any time, to (re)generate the output cs file.

*I have just tried and confirmed these steps work on a new WCF service project.*

### Extra trick:

As you're using Visual Studio 2010, you can also change the custom tool on the template from TextTemplatingFileGenerator to TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor temporarily.

This will spit out the underlying code directly into your project instead of the regular template output! Great for seeing what code is generated.

Comment: Thank, this seems to work rather well! I have the problem that the content of the .svc.tt file isn't syntax highlighted as C# in VStudio, but I guess that's another problem :)

Comment: tt files are not recognized by VS by default. There is at least one addin that allows for tt file syntax highlighting, but you may also be able to add the tt extension to the list of C# file extensions (not sure where to do this off the top of my head).

Comment: I found for instance the Tangible T4 Editor, but it doesn't auto-indent :(

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is correct, *but not for the question asked*!**

**Thanks for clarifying the question, new answer added - this one will be moved/deleted:)**

In theory you can generate any type of text file with a TT file. We use it to generate database scripts, config files etc (Microsoft use it for all sorts of proxy generation).

The problem you have is that the Reference.cs file for a service reference is initially generated too, so you will have to stop that process as well.

- Click the "show all files" button in the solution browser. This will expose the underlying Reference.cs file.
- Open the reference.cs file and save it as a .TT extension. **This must be done first as following steps cause the .cs file to vanish!**
- Include the new Reference.tt file into the project.
- Remove the "WCF Proxy Generator" Custom Tool option from the Reference.svcmap file.
- If you are under source control, undo any pending delete of the Reference.cs file. This delete is automatically caused by the previous step.
- Ensure the custom build option of the Reference.tt file is `TextTemplatingFileGenerator`. *It should add this by default when you rename the cs file*.
- Add the language type you want to use for your TT scripting to the top of the Reference.tt file (always good to be explicit):

  <#@ template language="C#" #>

### Extra trick:

As you're using Visual Studio 2010, you can also change the custom tool on the template from TextTemplatingFileGenerator to TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor temporarily.

This will spit out the underlying code directly into your project instead of the regular template output! Great for seeing what code is generated.

*Note: If you are not after a .CS file as output you would also need to specify the output filename in the first entry of the script.* e.g. the minimum you would need at the top of the TT file would then be:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension="config" #>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like Visual Studio will allow me to rename the .svc.cs file. In the context menu there's no 'Rename' option.

Comment: instead of rename, do "Open File > Save As..." as he explained in his post.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding as regards my question. I'm not working with any WCF proxy in my project, I'm writing a WCF service. The service is defined by <service>.svc and its code-behind file <service>.svc.cs. <service>.svc has no Custom Tool option set AFAICT.

Comment: I will revise or delete this answer shortly now that you have clarified the question. Maybe you can ask the other (client) question anyway and I will copy this answer there? It was a good question too :)